# how to better link some sharepoint site(live site) using camelop php tools

Tags: php, sharepoint, camelot-.net-connector, camelot-php-tools

I have a live sharepoint site(http://moss.intranet.icimod.org). I want to connect this site with Php using Camelot Php tools.How do I get started with it.I have download Camelot Php Tools and also the camelot sharepoint connector and camelot sharepoint integration toolkit set. I have changed the settings.php but to no avail.Can anyone tell me how do i get started.
Any help or suggestions is welcome.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you made all necessary steps, there is a new guide available here
http://www.bendsoft.com/documentation/camelot-php-tools/2_0/installation/

The steps are as follows

1. Install the .NET Connector
2. Install and configure the Integration Toolkit
3. Test with PHP Tools

What most users forget is to **restart the Camelot SharePoint Integration Service** in services.msc after changing it's setup.

You can also have a look at this youtube movie, the first two minutes should cover this, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDtvcTnTbeM

If this doesn't resolve your issues contact the support of Bendsoft, support@bendsoft.com and someone will help you!